# Page Numbers in Header -> Use Footer Space

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, thesis

I successfully moved the page numbers from the footer to the header of each page using scrlayer-scrpage. Now there is some "free" space on the bottom of each page.

i) Is it possible to reclaim that space for the text area?

ii) If so, how?

iii) Is this procedure even advisable? Will it be covered by "DIV=calc"?

I'm using KOMAscript, namely scrartcl. By the way, this is for my master thesis in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the KOMA-Script documentation, section »2.6. Adjusting the Type Area and Page Layout«, describtion of options `headinclude` and `footinclude`.

> Clearly an empty footer or header belongs to the margins, since it cannot be distinguished from the rest of the margins. A footer that contains only the pagination looks more like a margin and should therefore be counted as such.

So for the calculation of the type area there is no difference between an empty footer or a footer containing only the page number. Note that package `typearea` calculates the margins so that ratio of the top and bottom margins is nearly 1:2. See section »2.1. Fundamentals of Page Layout« for more information.

If you want to decrease/change the bottom margin, you could use option `usegeometry` and load package `geometry` with option `bottom=<length>`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  usegeometry% <- add this option
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\usepackage[bottom=116pt]{geometry}% <- change the bottom margin

\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

This is not covered by `DIV=calc`.

Comment: Then I will keep the predefined typesetting for now. That was very helpful though. Thanks! :)